# Fast Fourrier Transform of real measurements in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to perform the fast fourrier transform to non uniformly sampled data . The output is in the following image [image]

It was obtained using the following code in **MATLAB**

```
%% x is the sampled signal
%% t is the sampling instances
L=size(x,1);
t_new = linspace(t(1),t(end),L); 

% Performing interpolation to obtain a uniformly sampled signal
x_new_cubic = interp1(t,x,t_new,'cubic'); 
x_new_pchip =interp1(t,x,t_new,'pchip');
x_new_spline = interp1(t,x,t_new,'spline');

NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
X = fft(x_new_cubic,NFFT)/L;
F=1000*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

figure;

subplot(121);
plot(F,20*log10(abs(X(1:NFFT/2+1))));
xlabel('Frequency[Hz]');
ylabel('|X|[dB]');
w =  hamming(L,'periodic');
x_win = w.*x_new_cubic(1:L)';
X_win = fft(x_win,NFFT)/L;

subplot(122);
plot(F,20*log10(abs(X_win(1:NFFT/2+1))));
xlabel('Frequency[Hz]');
ylabel('|X|[dB]');
title('Hamming Window')
```

It seems that I can't trust such result, but I am not sure too. Can any one give me some advice?

Comment: Your code is unreadable in its current form, but I can tell you that the fft() function assumes that its input is evenly spaced. I don't know what you'll get if it's not, but it won't be the DFT.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I did an interpolation first, to obtain a uniformly sampled data

Comment: You need to use a resampling method that includes filtering. You can't just interpolate with splines and and the like and expect the spectrum to be as it should. Also, you'll get more visibility from the right people if you add the signal-processing tag. The dsp stackexchange site is another option for help on things like this.

Comment: Migrating by OP request.

Comment: Actually, interpolation should be useful. I don't know what the question actually is.

Comment: @user7358 Interpolating needs to followed by filtering to remove spectral replicas.

Comment: @user7358 , I cannot interpret the fft result, hence I can't trust it. Maybe it due to spectral replicas as mentionned by AnonSubmitter85 , but I must admit that I don't know how exactly do I have to filter

Comment: Not clear what the question is here. I'm not sure why you think you can't trust the result. Your approach doesn't seem unreasonable, although we don't know what your signal is supposed to be.

Comment: @JasonR , I am not sure, as the frequencies are not something I expected.

Comment: Do pchip or spline give any less problematic results?  Your use of the hamming window shows that there are lots of frequency spikes below the rectangular sidelobe level. You'd have to tell us what you're expecting the signal to be.